# World time in flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I am trying to build a world app with different country timezone's. I am able to get the time using api but when api was called, time of that particular instance is being displayed and is not updated every minute. Is there any particular method to achieve this?

```
  void getTime() async{
    Response response =
    await get('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Australia/Sydney');
    Map dataAus = jsonDecode(response.body);
    String dateTimeAus = dataAus['datetime'];
    String offsetAus = dataAus['utc_offset'].substring(1, 3);
    DateTime nowAus = DateTime.parse(dateTimeAus);
    nowAus = nowAus.add(Duration(hours: int.parse(offsetAus)));
  }
```

Comment: Locale with intl can't be  used? instead of API call?

Comment: Is it possible to get time of other countries as well? using intl?

Comment: I guess so, using Locale maybe

Answer (score 0):

I figured the solution, there might be many other efficient approaches anyway my work is done. Used Timer to call the api every second.

```
getTime(String country, continent) async {
    Response response =
        await get('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/$continent/$country');
    Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    String dateTime = data['datetime'];
    String offset = data['utc_offset'].substring(1, 3);
    DateTime time = DateTime.parse(dateTime);
    time = time.add(Duration(hours: int.parse(offset)));
    final timeStr = DateFormat('hh : mm a').format(time);
    return timeStr.substring(0, 10);
  }

  Timer timer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      Timer(
        Duration(seconds: 1) - Duration(milliseconds: _localDateTime.second),
        _updateTime,
      );
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void getTime() async{
    Response response =
    await 
    http.get(Uri.parse('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Australia/Sydney'));
    Map dataAus = jsonDecode(response.body);
    String dateTimeAus = dataAus['datetime'];
    String offsetAus = dataAus['utc_offset'].substring(1, 3);
    DateTime nowAus = DateTime.parse(dateTimeAus);
    nowAus = nowAus.add(Duration(hours: int.parse(offsetAus)));
  }
```